# What is mapped to Super+P?

Tags: shortcut-keys

When I click <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> it messes up my display settings (the monitors go black and after that their arrangement is reset to the default one).

I tried to find what the action is in Ubuntu, but running the following returns nothing:

```
gsettings list-keys org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings | while read key; do gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings $key; done | grep Super
```

What else may be mapped to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and how can I find it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close, but the setting is not where you searched. Instead:

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep "<Super>p"
```

reveals that `<Super>p` is defined under switch-monitor. By default, also the key `'XF86Display'`is assigned to this function.

You can use dconf-editor to change the assignment, or use following commands:

- To disable `<Super>p` and keep `XF86Display`:

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.mutter.keybindings switch-monitor "['XF86Display']"
  ```
- To disable all related shortcut keys:

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.mutter.keybindings switch-monitor "['']"
  ```
- To reset to the defaults:

  ```
  gsettings reset org.gnome.mutter.keybindings switch-monitor
  ```